# How to pull total video view count from Facebook page to display live counter on website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a live view counter on a website which shows the number of times views a certain Facebook page I manage has across all of its videos. I'm new to using APIs, so how could this be accomplished using HTML/JS?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mahogany I have looked at the Facebook developers site and could only find API access for a single video's view count. Is there a way to have this reach across an entire page's video view count?

Comment: all videos? i doubt that there is any api for it. btw, there is no html/js involved, this is a general question and should not be tagged with specific programming languages. also, the api tag is marked with "do not use", so i replace it with the graph api tag.

Comment: Ahh, OK. Thank you for that information. I'll tag accordingly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a completely controlled solution - you'll need a script that checks based on some kind of logic as to when your video has been watched and store that number into a database of some sort. If you went this route, you could setup something super simple like a firebase database and just have a counter. Add 1 to it each time your logic condition is passed.

But there's plenty of services that can aid you. Using Google analytics, you can get stats up and running much easier. You could use [this](https://www.9lessons.info/2016/04/track-html5-video-views-with-google.html) link. This method requires trackers, which some people block. But it would probably give you a pretty solid estimate depending on your user base.